# Add Where clause to only select records within certain date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, stored-procedures

I have a table with a column "`dateRec`" formatted as datetime and a Select procedure to fetch data from this table. 
The procedure has two input parameters, `rangeStart` and `rangeEnd` which can be either formatted as datetime or as nvarchar (whatever makes sense here).

How can I achieve that I only select records where dateRec is between rangeStart and rangeEnd ?

**My procedure (shortened) - just to demonstrate what I am looking for:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchRequests]
    @rangeStart datetime,
    @rangeEnd datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      logID,
                flag,
                reviewer,
                dateRec
    FROM        LogRequests
    WHERE       dateRec >= rangeStart
    AND         dateRec <= rangeEnd
    FOR XML PATH('requests'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Mike.

Comment: what is wrong with this?

Comment: as @Nithesh says, are there errors with this or is this simply a code review?

Comment: Because the parameter is `datetime` if you pass an NVARCHAR it will be cohereced into a datetime *before the procedure starts*. So, basically, what's wrong with your existing code?

Comment: @Mike You didn't use variables correctly, you need to add a @ sign. Please see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks - so this is actually correct ? I didnt expect I can select the dates that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the keyword BETWEEN:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchRequests]
    @rangeStart datetime,
    @rangeEnd datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT      logID,
                flag,
                reviewer,
                dateRec
    FROM        LogRequests
    WHERE       dateRec BETWEEN @rangeStart AND @rangeEnd
    FOR XML PATH('requests'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('ranks')
END
```

Comment: Thanks for this ! Will this include the rangeStart date and the rangeEnd date ? Also, what format would I need to pass along the parameters for this procedure ? Would something like 2014-01-31 work or does the input have to be in a certain format ?

Comment: Yes BETWEEN returns TRUE if the value of test_expression is greater than or equal to the value of begin_expression and less than or equal to the value of end_expression.

Comment: Use function SELECT GETDATE() to determine your default datetime format configured for the server.

Comment: For data literal strings, use a neutral dateformat like unseparated yyyymmdd or ISO 8601 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).  If called from application code, simply use properly typed parameters and the API will convert to the proper internal binary format.